# The differential equation $u'\cdot v + A\cdot u = w$

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, differential-algebraic-equations

Let $A\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a matrix valued function, and $v, w\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ vector fields. I want to find a function/vector field $u\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ that satisfies

$$ u'(x) \cdot v(x) + A(x)\cdot u(x)=w(x) $$

for all $x$. Is this a known differential equation? Does it have a name?

I guess one could call this a *first order linear partial differential algebraic equation*. Searching for *linear PDAE* yields some results that seem to deal with similar equations when $A, v, w$ are constant ([one example](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228993742_Index_and_Characteristic_Analysis_of_Linear_PDAE_Systems)). Anyway, I am still looking for sources and was just hoping that maybe someone has seen something like this before. Ideally I would hope that there is a way to analytically solve it given $v,w$ and $A$.